# Show there is no continuous bijection between topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with topology $\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$
and 
$Y=\{1,2,3\}$ with topology $\{Y,\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{2\}\}$

Show there is no continuous bijection $X\to Y$.

I’ve not proved one does or doesn’t exist before to do with topologies and I’m unsure how to tackle this.

Comment: There are only 6 bijections.  You could check them all.

Comment: @Randall I am completely lost how this is done for topological spaces I only understand how to do this for functions, do I define some function between them?

Comment: Here's a typical bijection: $a \mapsto 2, b \mapsto 1, c \mapsto 3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology on $Y$ has two open sets of two elements namely, $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$. Under a  bijective continuous function the inverse image of these two open sets must be two different open sets of $X$ with two elements in each.  The given topology on $X$ does not have such open sets.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous bijection. Since $f^{-1}[\{2\}]$ must be open, we must have $f(a)=2$. So what can you say about $f^{-1}[\{1,2\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{2,3\}]$?

[Note that since $f$ is a bijection, $f^{-1}[V]$ has the same size as $V$ for all $V \subseteq Y$.]

Answer (score 0):

By contradiction. Suppose such an $f$ exists. Then because $f$ is continuous, the preimages of each of the open sets in the topology on $Y$ must be open sets in $X$. There are 6 open sets in $Y$, five in $X$. Hence there must be two open sets in $Y$ whose preimages are the same. That's impossible for a bijection: no two distinct sets can have the same preimages.